# Linux kernel 3.9 new storage features howto?

Tags: linux, raid, cache, kernel, btrfs

Linux kernel 3.9 has been released, which brings new features for storage cache devices (dm-cache), as well as BTRFS RAID 5/6. These features are undoubtedly sexy, but are all but completely undocumented. I am rebuilding my storage system and would like to take advantage of these technologies if at all possible.

Does anyone know of a guide on how to get started with them, and if they can be used together?

Comment: I have read the git comments for these patches, but they do not provide a howto for using these new features. They merely describe them. I doubt that mkfs.btrfs that comes with most distributions is updated to support the new features, either. This is why I asked the question.

Comment: Anyone have an answer to this? Am I the only one who wants to take advantage of these new features?